# Update all or only where oldvalue<>newvalue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm using SQL server 2014.

Which would run faster, why, and is there a way to use the analyzer to find out:

```
update tablename set flname=replace(flname,'(','')

update tablename set flname=replace(flname,'(','') where flname<>replace(flname,'(','')
```

No indices on `flname` field. I could create one though. I expect the where would filter out about 90% of rows.

Comment: Keep the WHERE clause! Will make transaction size smaller. `where flname like '%(%'`.

Comment: use `set statistics time on` and run your horses ;)

Comment: Smaller transactions also means smaller risk of transaction conflicts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple repro that shows that the expression `REPLACE (flname ,'(','')` will be evaluated **twice** in case of `WHERE flname <> REPLACE (flname ,'(','')`, and it's CPU intensive work:

```
select col
into dbo.update_str
from
(
select top 1000 replicate ('a((', 2666) as col
from dbo.nums
union all
select top 1000 replicate ('a', 8000)
from sys.all_columns
)t


set statistics io,  time on
update dbo.update_str set col = replace (col ,'(','')

   --CPU time = 12278 ms,  elapsed time = 12299 ms.


drop table dbo.update_str

select col
into dbo.update_str
from
(
select top 1000 replicate ('a((', 2666) as col
from dbo.nums
union all
select top 1000 replicate ('a', 8000)
from sys.all_columns
)t


update dbo.update_str set col = replace (col ,'(','') where 
col <> replace (col ,'(','')

   --CPU time = 23946 ms,  elapsed time = 24007 ms.
```

In my test I fill in the table `dbo.update_str` 2 times beacuse if it's filled only once the second update has nothing to do.

Double work in the second case san be found out in the execution plan: while both plans have `COMPUTE SCALAR` after a scan (to calculate a value for `UPDATE`), the second has the same expression as a `predicate` of table scan.

So in my test case where the half of data has '(' in it, the time difference is 2 times on 2000 rows (of course my rows are long enough to show the worst possible case), the second update is 2 time slower because the rows have many characters to replace.

Answer (score 0):

In my test it does not matter.

You can test as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 flname INTO #TEST FROM tablename 

SET STATISTICS IO,  TIME ON
UPDATE #TEST SET flname = REPLACE (flname ,'(','')

UPDATE #TEST SET flname = REPLACE (flname ,'(','') WHERE 
flname <> REPLACE (flname ,'(','')
```